# Pandas: operations between multiindex dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two multiindex dataframes. They have three levels of headers (ISIN, Name, FX)

The first dataframe contains assets expressed in diferents currencies. In order to make it simple Ill show just two assets expressed in USD. This dataframe is named df_assets

```
**ISIN    23442     03483  
  Name   Share A   Share B 
   FX      USD       USD**
  01/21   17.2       210.2
  02/21   15.9       222.8
```

The second dataframe cotains FX prices. Has the same three level multiindex as dataframe 1. THis dataframe is named df_fx:

```
 **ISIN    11134     23456  
  Name    EUR/USD    EUR/PHP 
   FX      USD        EUR**
  01/21   1.15       55.5
  02/21   1.20       56.5
```

What I want is to trasnform the values of the df_assets to euros using the information of df_fx. The result should be like this:

df_fx:

```
**ISIN    23442     03483  
  Name   Share A   Share B 
   FX      EUR       EUR**
  01/21   14.96      182.78
  02/21   13.25      185.66
```

What I have tried is this:

```
  for currency, isin in zip(df_assets.columns.get_level_values(level=2), 
    df_assets.columns.get_level_values(level = 0)):
    print(currency, isin)
    for fx in df_fx.columns.get_level_values(level = 2):
        print(fx)
        if currency == fx and currency == "USD":
            df_assets[isin] = df_assets[isin] * 1/df_fx[11134]
```

What is returning is df_assets with the columns with assets in usd empty.

How could I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I THINK you are overcomplicating your problem, based on your sample:

- MultiIndex is unnecessary
- looping is unnecessary

I would say your MultiIndex columns and your index isnt set up properly but — if you absolutely require this setup — try this:

```
df_assets = pd.DataFrame({('ISIN', 'Name', 'FX'): {0: '01/21', 1: '02/21'},
 ('23442', 'Share A', 'USD'): {0: 17.2, 1: 15.9},
 ('03483', 'Share B', 'USD'): {0: 210.2, 1: 222.8}})

df_fx = pd.DataFrame({('ISIN', 'Name', 'FX'): {0: '01/21', 1: '02/21'},
 ('11134', 'EUR/USD', 'USD'): {0: 1.15, 1: 1.2},
 ('3456', 'UR/PHP', 'EUR'): {0: 55.5, 1: 56.5}})

print((1 / df_fx.loc[:, '11134']).values * df_assets.loc[:, ['23442', '03483']])

       23442       03483
     Share A     Share B
         USD         USD
0  14.956522  182.782609
1  13.250000  185.666667
```